# Is there a way to save a type in a variable to use it for generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class Cake<Filling>{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Filling> fillings;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

In my main method, I reference the same type multiple times with different generics:

```
public class Main {
    
    private static void printMenu(String[] options){
      
       Cake<String> cake = new Cake();
       // some code
       ArrayList<String> fillings = new ArrayList<String>();
       // some code
       Stack<String> fillingsStack= new Stack<String>();
       // more code


    }

}
```

So right now everything related to fillings is String, but I might need to change the type in the future and that means manually searching the code for  that relate to filling stuff.
Is there a way to make a variable, say something like:

```
public class Main {

    Type fillingType = <String>
    private static void printMenu(String[] options){
      
       Cake<**fillingType **> cake = new Cake<String>();
       // some code
       ArrayList<**fillingType **> fillings = new ArrayList<String>();
       // some code
       Stack<**fillingType **> fillingsStack= new Stack<String>();
       // more code


    }

}
```

Maybe there is an elegant way to acomplish this

I've tried to google the issue, but found that there is no way to save a type to a variable

Comment: Why would you need that? Generics are compile-time information that is used for compiler checks, but is not present at runtime. Variables are runtime data that is not present at compile time... the only way to keep type information at runtime is to save [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object... but that won't help you with compiler checks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I thought that there is some pattern to avoid hardcoding types in generics, like when the same value is used multiple times in the code, it is good to make it a variable, or something like typedef in c++. If I understood correctly, it is not possible, or impractical, to do that with generics in java?

Comment: `new Cake()` is a raw type and should be `new Cake<>()`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I've corrected the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could make the method itself generic:

```
private static <T> Cake<T> makeCake() {
   final Cake<T> cake = new Cake<>();
   // some code
   final List<T> fillings = new ArrayList<>();
   // some code
   final Stack<T> fillingsStack= new Stack<>();
   // more code

   return cake;
}
```

Note that modern code should prefer to use `ArrayDeque` over `Stack`